# #pragma is used in a strange way

Tags: c, pragma

First of all, I have seen tons of answers related to the usage of `#pragma`. But none of them is related to my specific question. The only one related is from [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/compiler/ref/rnpgmcfn.htm).

```
int add_logical(int, int);
#pragma mc_func add_logical {"7c632014" "7c630194"}
/*   addc       r3 <- r3, r4           */
/*   addze      r3 <- r3, carry bit    */

#pragma reg_killed_by add_logical gr3, xer
/* only gpr3 and the xer are altered by this function */

main() {

int i,j,k;

i = 4;
k = -4;
j = add_logical(i,k);
printf("\n\nresult = %d\n\n",j);
}
```

The part I don't understand is the meaning of `{"7c632014" "7c630194"}`. Could someone explain a little bit?

I also have a similar case:

```
#pragma mc_func function {type1, type2}
```

Where `function` is defined and `type1` and `type2` are two structs.
I really have no idea how "function" is related to `type1` and `type2`.

Comment: Looks like you are reading [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc%2Fcompiler%2Fref%2Frnpgmcfn.htm). It's creating a function in machine language. The translation from ml->asm is in the comments below.

Comment: I am utterly horrified to learn that such a thing exists.

Comment: Me too. You really have no idea why people wrote codes in such a way.